# libGDX error in opening zip file

Tags: android, macos, libgdx, game-engine

I hope that someone here will be able to help me..
I'm working on Mac OS X and trying to build my gradle project 
I keep getting the following problem:

```
Generating app in /Users/AsafM/Desktop/untitled
Executing '/Users/AsafM/Desktop/untitled/gradlew clean --no-daemon eclipse afterEclipseImport'
Unzipping /Users/AsafM/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all/7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj/gradle-1.11-all.zip to /Users/AsafM/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all/7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> General -> Exisiting Projects into Workspace
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> YourProject.ipr
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can download the gradle-1.11-all.zip file manually from http://www.gradle.org/downloads to replace the corrupted file.

What's happening is LibGDX is trying to extract the files, but the zip file is corrupted. So replacing the file with a clean copy works, or if you delete it, LibGDX will download it for you automatically, so it's really the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am also encountered this problem. My solution is go to "dist" in .gradle directory and delete all of them, then create libgdx project is successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I eventually solved it by doing the following :

1. Open terminal
2. Enter : rm -fr ~/.gradle
3. Enter : rm -rf ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-bin
4. Close terminal
5. Run ./gradlew build

Answer (score 0):

Go to /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper-properties

Change: the distributionUrl to

distributionUrl =http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip